# Lucene Multiple delete query (JSON)

Tags: json, logging, lucene, elasticsearch

I have a problem with a script that i wrote for elasticsearch. On my server I have multiple log files that need to be deleted on a daily basis. To automate this process I wrote a Perl script that deletes my keep alive log files.

Basically an curl XDELETE

But now I want to add a query to delete another log file. 
IS IT POSSIBLE TO ADD ANOTHER JSON OBJECT, WITH OUT CREATING ANOTHER DELETE VARIABLE?

So adding something to my JSON that integrates a separate queries that also deletes that log?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "to": "2014-08-24T00:00:00.000+01:00"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "log_message"
            ],
            "query": "keepAlive"
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

(Something Like &&? adding a second bool query)

Because everything I add will just over specify the query that i have leading to results I do not want.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure I've correctly understood what your looking for, but it sounds like you want to combine the results of the given query with those of some other separate query.  In that case, you can nest boolean queries as should clauses, something like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "@timestamp": {
                    "to": "2014-08-24T00:00:00.000+01:00"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "fields": [
                    "log_message"
                  ],
                  "query": "keepAlive"
                }
              },
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          **Another query here**
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```